# How to Force a Google Test Case to Run Last

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Our team has a very mature suite of Google Test (GTest) test cases.  The test cases, via a custom test environment, build up a test report in addition to the standard JUnit XML output that GTest produces on its own.

I would like to add one final test that ensures that the Google Test suite produced its test report after all other tests in the suite execute.  In other words, I would like to force which test executes last so it can write the custom output and then verify that it was properly written, failing if it was not.

The solution should work even if Google Test is executing tests in random order.  Can I force one test to run last?  Can I write a test that GTest won't automatically discover, call it myself from my "main", and have its results rolled into the rest of them, or ??

I see no way to do this with the current GTest API, but thought it was worth asking.

Comment: spawn the google test from an outer test process, wait on its PID and then read the output?

Comment: There are certainly hack options, but I really would like something that fits nicely into the test architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closest to what you're looking for.

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite

Perhaps you can use the destruction of the static object to collect information about all tests that ran.

However, beware of forks.

I really would write your own `main()`, fork the test process and wait for the child to finish so you can collect data from it.